# Spring data - JPA, missing IDs

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data

We are using a spring data project, we have a mysql database.
Lately we have noticed the following on the USER table:

```
id  |   name |  pass | email
=====================================
1      John      123     john@gmail.com

2      Joe      456       joe@gmail.com

3      .....

4   ....

6 ...
```

Well apparently id=5 is missing from our database.

1. What could be the reason for that? Bear in mind we are using @transactional services and dao.
2. Can spring data create new entries with these skipped ids? (configuration maybe?)

Comment: if you had 5 entries, deleted 1 and then created other entries and your id is auto generated, i think it will skip 5

Comment: No deletion takes place in our project at all.

Answer (score 1):

The id get 'reserved' when you issue an `insert` statement, but the insertion is performed until the transaction is commited; if an exception is thrown before that, the transaction gets rolled back, the insertion is not performed, so the reserved id is not used. All of this is assuming you're using auto-increments.

There might be other reasons, but this one in particular has happened to me a on ocassion, although is not really an issue to me.

Edit: this has happened to me on Postgres but I think it also happened on mysql; it's been a while since I last used it.

Also, you can check your JPA provider's the documentation on `@GeneratedValues`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can spring data create new entries with these skipped ids? (configuration maybe?)

Comment: I don't think so, but you can try. You can certainly insert them manually (specifying an id instead of using the auto-increment) directly in MySQL, but I haven't tried it through JPA.